# Java - Using Threads to Start - Pause - Stop a Miniature Programming World

Tags: java, multithreading

I am still having difficulties to properly work with Threads. I know the basic gist of how to start one, but the biggest problems I have is with pausing - resuming and stopping them all together.
Whenever I tried stopping my Simulation Thread, which runs a main Method, that may contain a loop itself, I need to be able to pause that Thread with a Button in my GUI.
Pausing and Stopping the thread always leads to the whole GUI to freeze, thus making it impossible.

I got my Gui Controller connected to the Simulation Manager Class, that creates a new Simulation based on the given class1 and class2. This Manager should keep track of the current state and work the threads in the Simulation class (extends Thread).

```java
public void startProg() {
        if(simulation == null){
            simulation = new Simulation (class1, class2, this);
        }
        if(state.getState () == SimulationsStatus.PAUSE){
            simulation.resumeProg ();  -- Basically where i call the Simulation object to resume / start
            System.out.println ("startProg-resume" );

     ...
        }
```

My Simulation starts like this:

```java
   public synchronized void startSimulation() {
       s = new Simulation (class1,class2,simulationManager); --- Wether i assign my Simulation s to a 
--- new one or the current object this is in does not change the outcome 
       s.start ( );
    }
```

In that Class i have 4 methods, start, resume, pause and stop that should do the named thing to the thread itself. I am out of ideas how to get the current thread to stop without freezing the Program itself.

**This is the run method of that thread object, the main method can contain infinite loops if the user designs its code that way in my gui, so the pause and stop methods should be able to pause and stop a thread even if its currently calculating something**

```java
    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
            try {
                class1.main ( );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println (e.getStackTrace ( ));
        }
    }
```

Any tips are really appreciated

Currently I am using a observer pattern to "freeze" the thread for set amount of time so that class1 moves in a fixed speed on screen

Comment: If your classes are just Java programs, not some "play language", then you'll need to run this in debug mode, using an agent. You can't pause, stop or resume threads in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stopping threads, and pausing/resuming threads with no support from the code that runs inside them is **not supported** on the JVM.

See for example [the documentation on Thread.stop](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()).

If you want to run code you don't know or trust and wish to control it, run it in its own VM, preferably in a virtual machine environment. That way you can control the virtual machine.

Comment: I talked to my Professor about it and it kind of works with a combination of a State-Enum, wait&notify in combination with the update method as Observer. Probably not the nicest piece of code but it works. Thank you for your input though!